# Excel asks for password when opening from browser using application link

Tags: excel, browser, ms-office

when I'm on a doimain joined computer and I open excel using application link this

```
ms-excel:ofe|u|https://mysite.mydomain.sk/api/documents/order/customersheet/12344.xlsx
```

the Excel asks for password.

1. The password does not work (seems like it is trying to authenticate against my web app, not a domain controller)
2. I need to cancel the login 5x, then the sheet is loaded and then cancel another 3x

How do I prevent this nonsense from happening?

[image]